# Append in For loop does not work

Tags: list-manipulation

I need to break my for loop in case of an thrown message and append s to the result list. Breaking the loop works, but my result is empty. I can not use `Table[]` because it does not support `Break[]`.

EDIT: s has the form of list, so I get a Table structure for result

EDIT 2: `AppendTo[]` yields empty result too.

```
result = {};
For[i = 0, i < 6, i++, 
 s = {Quiet[
    Check[If[i == 3, Message[FindRoot::jsing, x, 1], i], "Nan", 
     FindRoot::jsing]]};
 If[s == "Nan", Break[], AppendTo[result, s]];
 ]
result
```

yields:

```
{}
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
result = {};
For[i = 0, i < 6, i++, 
 s = Check[If[i == 3, Message[FindRoot::jsing, x, 1], i], "Nan", 
   FindRoot::jsing];
 Print[s];
 If[s == "Nan", Break[], result = {result, s}];]
Flatten[result]
```

or

```
result = {};
For[i = 0, i < 6, i++, 
 s = Check[If[i == 3, Message[FindRoot::jsing, x, 1], i], "Nan", 
   FindRoot::jsing];
 Print[s];
 If[s == "Nan", Break[], AppendTo[result, {s, dim}]];]
result
```

Comment: this works for one dimensional form of s but not for lists (edited problem, sorry)

Comment: second one has table structure, thank you.

Answer (score 16):

The reason `Append[]` isn't working in your loop is that it returns a new list with your new element added to the end.

If you want to change the list in place, you should use `AppendTo[]` instead.

Comment: thx, now I know why Append in loops is evil!

Comment: @MartinScherer Oh no, the main reason for that (`Append` being evil in loops) is not it. It is that the full list is copied to append a single element.

Comment: calling copy constructors all the time :)

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, which suggests an interesting follow-up question. Is `AppendTo`'s implementation equally eager to copy things repeatedly? I can imagine an implementation where the `Append` version is forced to copy with every operation, but where `AppendTo` is implemented much like C++'s `std::vector` and only has to copy some of the time instead of on every step. I just ran some `Timing`s and it looks like their behavior is almost identical.

Comment: @sblom I have once implemented a dynamic array structure in Mathematica, which does have this behavior (not that it is very hard). Didn't have time to polish it and publish, but perhaps this is not a bad idea. It is a little at odds with idiomatic Mathematica programming though, since it has a state. I think, the real reason why it is not that much useful in practice, is that most of the time, people don't want random access to the prepared list (just the ability to add in constant time) - and used linked lists. and when they do, it will be too slow anyways (top-level implementation).

Comment: @LeonidShifrin While we're on this topic, I mostly use `old = {new, old}` to grow a list, but do you have any insights on the performance of `Join`? For example, `{new} ~Join~ old` vs. `old ~Join~ {new}`? If it's better than `Append` and only marginally worse than linked lists, then it provides a way to add quickly and have easy access to an arbitrary element. I use this at times for moderately sized lists and found it quite convenient. However, I don't know (and haven't spent time poking) how `Join` works and whether it copies the entire list too... thoughts?

Comment: @R.M. `Join` surely copies lists, it has no other choice :). So, it is no better than `Append`, at least conceptually (I do not remember the results of micro-benchamrking and am actually being increasingly annoyed by the fact that the language encourages this massive waste of time and effort). Using linked lists is different because at every given iteration, there are only two elements in the list - a newly added one and a pointer to the old list. The fact that pointers are not available to us explicitly, is irrelevant - the point is that there is no massive copying.

Comment: @R.M. Also, you *can not* provide both fast addition and fast lookup (random access) without more sophisticated data structures, such as hash tables or binary search trees. You can sort of do this (for the average time of addition) with dynamic arrays, but as I said, this does not make much sense for the top-level code anyways - since if you need random access then chances are that your top-level code using it will be slow.

Comment: @sblom I noticed that I did not really answer your question. The answer is yes, `AppendTo` is just as bad in this regard as `Append`. Moreover, you can see that `AppendTo` has been actually implemented with `Set` and `Append`, by using `On[Set]`, and then say `a = Range[5];
AppendTo[a, 6]`.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Thanks for the very clear explanation :)

Answer (score 4):

You may not be able to use `Table` with `Break[]` but you can use `Do`:

> Break[]
>       exits the nearest enclosing Do, For or While.

I also prefer [`Sow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Sow.html) and [`Reap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Reap.html) for speed and flexibility.

```
Reap[
  Do[
    s = Check[If[i == 3, Message[FindRoot::jsing, x, 1], i], "Nan", FindRoot::jsing];
    If[s == "Nan", Break[], Sow@s],
    {i, 0, 5}
  ]
][[2, 1]]
```

> ```
> {0, 1, 2}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

In an effort to "say no to loops", here is an alternative that substitutes `For` and `Break` with `Fold` and a `Throw`/`Catch` construct. There might be another alternative using `FoldList` and fewer uses of `Flatten`, but it's late at night here and I wasn't able to get that quite working. This works:

```
Catch@Fold[
  With[{chk = 
      Check[If[#2 == 3, Message[FindRoot::jsing, x, 1], #2], "Nan", 
       FindRoot::jsing]},
    If[chk == "Nan", Throw[Flatten@{#1, #2}], 
     Flatten@{#1, chk}]] &, {}, Range[6] ]
```

`FindRoot::jsing: Encountered a singular Jacobian at the point x = 1.
 Try perturbing the initial point(s). >>`

`{1, 2, 3}`

I think approaches such as this are preferable to `For` loops, since the latter tends to result in iterator variables (in this case, `i`) that remain globally defined, which is probably not what you want.