# professionalize/optimize my code that calls a function

Tags: functions, function-construction, code-review

I have the following construction, which defines a function that I subsequently call in a loop multiple times. I use this very often, but I have never looked into if there is a more professional way to do it in Mathematica. I would be happy to get feedback on my following MWE

```
g[x_] := Log[x] + 1000;

f[a_, x_, c_] := {
   temp = 4*a*c + g[a] // N;
   a + temp};

data = {};
For[i = 1, i < 10, i++,
 data = Append[data, {i, f[i, 1, 1][[1]]}]]
```

EDIT: The inner part of the function `f` is not important, it could be anything.

Comment: I would like this Q&A to be called something like "the dangers of using append in a loop".

Comment: `Append` copies the list that is its first argument every time it is called. About `1/2 n^2` copies of elements are made this way, where `n` is the length of the resulting list. You really only need of the order of n instructions to do this, for example by using a linkedList, or by figuring out the size of the of the result list beforehand.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to optimize? The function? Or "the code that calls the function"?

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29349/131

Comment: See also [this](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2009/Apr/msg00820.html) by Daniel Lichtblau. [This Q&A](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28851/4330) is related, but that one still requires some work. Also related is [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4496/4330) but the main issue there is something else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function `g` appears to be defined correctly.

The function `f` uses a global Symbol without localizing it.  Either use `Module` or write the function in such as way that this Symbol is not needed.  For example:

```
f[a_, x_, c_] := Module[{temp},
  {temp = 4*a*c + g[a] // N;
   a + temp}
];
```

Or:

```
f[a_, x_, c_] := {a + N[4*a*c + g[a]]};
```

The accumulation of `data` is inefficient in both syntax and computation.  Use the built in iterator constructs such as `Do`, `Table`, `Sum`, `Fold`, and `Nest` rather than `For` loops whenever possible.  See [Alternatives to procedural loops and iterating over lists in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7924/121).

Further, your use of `Append` causes reallocation of the low level array that *Mathematica* uses for a `List`, therefore your `Append` will take time proportional to the length of the list rather than a constant time.  See [Select performance](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24167/121) and [Looking for a way to insert multiple elements into multiple positions simultaneously in a list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30647/looking-for-a-way-to-insert-multiple-elements-into-multiple-positions-simultaneo/30648#30648) (Notes and Timings section).  If you *must* accumulate results incrementally use [`Sow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Sow.html) and [`Reap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Reap.html), or [linked lists](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25474/121).

Comment: exactly what i was looking for, thanks

Comment: @BillyJean Glad I could help. :-)

Comment: Personally I like not localising variables and catching unlocalised stuff later. My answer here is an example of this. I often make functions to show my intent, but inline them anyway so that they are not really used as functions.

Comment: How does [`AppendTo`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/AppendTo.html) fare in comparison to `Append` in terms of speed and memory efficiency?

Comment: @shrx `AppendTo` has the same performance; `AppendTo[x, n]` is merely a shorthand for `x = Append[x, n]`.  Speed is not really an issue with *short* lists, but since I believe in writing code that scales well I still repetitive `Append` operations.  Compare:   `small = Range[10];
Timing @ Do[AppendTo[small, n], {n, 1000}]` to `big = Range[1*^7];
Timing @ Do[AppendTo[big, n], {n, 1000}]` -- *huge* difference. (More than 4000 times slower on my system.)

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify your function definitions and you can use `Table` rather than For loop,ie.

```
g[x_] := Log[x] + 1000;    
f[a_, x_, c_] := a+ 4*a*c + g[a] // N;      
data=Table[{j,f[j, 1, 1]}, {j, 9}]
```

This yields the same result as your original code.

Comment: thanks for your contribution, however I am interested in "general optimization/suggestions", not anything that depends on what I specifically wrote inside `f`, please see my edit in OP. Thanks for comment on `Table`

Comment: @BillyJean ok. I look forward to other answers...

Answer (score 2):

This is perhaps a bit advanced, but I feel the technique used deserves to be shown.

In your case you can use `Compile`, as your functions deal with numeric values only. If `f` and `g` can be anything in a broader sense, then this solution method will not always work.

I have made a slight adaptation to your functions `f` and `g`. In your case you store the integer `i` as the first element of a list. However `i` can be inferred from the position of the element of the list, so I will not store it. This will also be more convenient for use in `Compile`, as our result Compile can not be a mix of integers and real numbers. Furthermore, I have changed all constants that were previously integers into real numbers, especially because that works nicely in `Compile`.

```
g[x_] := Log[x] + 1000.;

f[a_, x_, c_] :=
  (temp = 4.*a*c + g[a];
   a + temp);
```

Now we `Compile`

```
cfu =
 ReleaseHold@
  Hold[Compile][
   Hold[{{size, _Integer}}],
   (
     Hold[
       Block[
        {temp, res, iiii}
        ,
        res = ConstantArray[0., size];
        For[iiii = 1, iiii <= size, iiii++,

         res[[iiii]] = f[iiii // N, 1., 1.]
         ];
        res
        ]
       ] /. DownValues[f]
     ) /. DownValues[g]
   ,
   CompilationTarget -> "C"
   ]
```

It looks a bit strange perhaps, but for me this use of `DownValues` is a standard way to inline function definitions. For more on this, see my answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/38908/4330)

**Comparison**

```
nnnn = 1*^4;
```

`nnnn` will be the size of the data we use in this section.

```
(res = cfu2[nnnn]) // Timing // First
```

> 0.000307

```
(
   data = {};
   For[
    i = 1,
    i <= nnnn,
    i++,
    data = Append[data, {i, f[i, 1, 1]}]]
   ) // Timing // First
```

> 0.444171

So the timings favor the compiled function. The results are the same

```
data[[All, 2]] == res
```

> True

There is a difference in how the two are stored behind the scenes though

```
<< Developer`

PackedArrayQ@res
PackedArrayQ@data
```

> False 
>   True

To get the original "data format" back, you could do

```
data == Transpose[{Range[nnnn], res}]
```

> True

Comparison with ubpdqn

```
(data2 = Table[{j, f2[j, 1, 1]}, {j, nnnn}]; ) // Timing // First
```

> 0.050244

```
data2 == data
```

> True

**Reaction to comment**

*Possibly temporary*

The technique using `DownValues` can also be used with uncompiled functions. Here is an example and a comparison of timings

```
nnnn2 = 1*^5;

ff[x_] := ff2[x];
ff2[x_] := ff3[x];
ff3[x_] := x;

(res21 = Table[ff[x], {x, nnnn2}]) // Timing // First
```

> 0.052170

Now with inlining

```
SetAttributes[inl, HoldAll]
inl[expr_, f_] := ReleaseHold[Hold[expr] /. DownValues[f]]

gg3[x_] := x;
inl[gg2[x_] := gg3[x], gg3];
inl[gg[x_] := gg2[x], gg2]
(res22 = inl[Table[gg[x], {x, nnnn2}], gg]) // Timing // First
```

> 0.001950

```
(res23 = Table[x, {x, nnnn2}]) // Timing // First
```

Note that the last expression is basically equivalent to evaluating `Table[x, {x, nnnn2}]`. The overhead to make that expression is very small.

> 0.001767

```
res21 === res22 === res23 === Range[nnnn2]
```

> True

Comment: The inlining method you use with DownValues has a speedup purpose only within Compile or can help also in uncompiled code? I would say the former, but I am not sure.

Comment: @user8074 It can help with both :). See the last section of my answer, where I reply to your comment.